# Generic parameter of a generic class constructor

Tags: java, generics, parameters, constructor

Why can I compile this code without errors:

```
public class Base<T> {
    Base(List<String> list){}
}

class Child extends Base{
    Child(){
        super(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
}
```

But at the same time I can't compile this one (pay attention to `Base<T>`):

```
public class Base {
    Base(List<String> list){}
}

class Child extends Base{
    Child(){
        super(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
}
```

Obviously, there is "incompatible types" in the second example, but why is there no errors in the first one? It is unsafe and can lead to runtime exceptions, can't it?

Comment: In your first example, you're extending a raw type, therefore all use of generics is erased.

Comment: Excellent question. I see a 

```Note: Base.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.``` when I compile the first example, so it's not exactly without errors.

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer>` doesn't extend `List<String>`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, and what about the first example?

Comment: @eremeykin, in first example, when you use a raw type, all generic types will be lost.

Comment: @eremeykin, in second case, `super(new ArrayList<any class will able to be here>());`